# PHP: extension sysvmsg

Tags: php, message-queue, sysv

i use on my one personaly project simple queue implemented by [msg function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php). This a specific function [msg_receive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-receive.php) which is used to wait for a message to come to the queue. Once in a while, this wait crashes with a return **error code 43** without an error text.

I can cause this error number **43**. If I run two processes, you can see on [github](https://github.com/h4kuna/msg#how-simulate-error-with-code-43). This is expected, but if i run by supervisor i get same error.

[I created simple script on github](https://github.com/h4kuna/msg), which is executed by supervisor and process waiting for receive message, it sometomes happen the function return error code 43. Is there anything what clean resources?

I have no idea what causes this, but what did I try?

I checked that the supervisor runs only one php process and the PID is still the same.
I tested it on arm raspbian 32 bit (php 7.3.19) and ubuntu 64 bit (php 7.4.9), both are same.

Thank you for help.

I hope the behavior is well described.

Comment: You don't forget to use method ftok() for first parameter msg_get_queue($key)!

Comment: Let's use this library: https://github.com/h4kuna/queue